# Updating cells with new data from server, without reloading content that is the same - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that loads its data from a webService. I have a singleton object that keeps track of my data `(NSMutableArray *)`. When new data is loaded, I send a notification to my tableViewController and call `[self.tableView reloadData];` This redraws my table and populates the cells with the current data.

I have 2 problems with this.

1. If I am scrolling when the data is reloaded, the app crashes because the (NSMutableArray *) is empty for a second while the new data is loaded, and I get a `index 4 beyond bounds for empty array`
2. To fix this I did this `[_myArray removeAllObjects];` before I call `[self.tableView reloadData];` which fixes the crash, but clears all of the cells for a second, before drawing them again.

This is not the desired effect I want to achieve. I want it to reload the cells like the mail App, where it will draw and delete the necessary cells, and leave the ones that remain the same alone.

I also have tried `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade;` which animates the reload, but I still need to empty the array prior to reload.

How can I do this? I feel like I need to create a copy of the array, and then move it over, am I on the right path? here is my reload function.

```
- (void)reloadTable:(NSNotification *)notif {

    [self.sellingTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

*******UPDATE****

With guidance from @oren, here is what I came up with.. This works, but I fear for tables that have lots of Data, this wouldn't be efficient enough.  I tried to write a hashing algorithm that keeps and index for the comparison of the rows to reduce the iteration count, but was having issues with the ordering of result sets always being different..

I ultimately have 2 lists. One is a singleton list that I use to populate the table.. This is used instead of using a local Data storage like Core Data of SQLite 3, but those could also be used to keep data when your app is closed.

When I awake my app or load the view.. The data is loaded from my singleton List... I then create another array with data from the server, check both arrays against each other for changes and then add/remove rows where necessary.

```
-(void)sortRequestList:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    RequestManager *newListManager = [[RequestManager alloc] init];

    if ([notification.object isKindOfClass:[RequestManager class]])
    {
        newListManager = [notification object];//New Data that was downloaded from web
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error, object not recognized.");
    }

    NSLog(@"newListManager count = %lu", (unsigned long)newListManager.requestNotFilledList.count);
    NSLog(@"Before - requestNotFilledList count = %lu", (unsigned long)self.requestManager.requestNotFilledList.count);


    NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *deleteIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if ([self.requestManager.requestNotFilledList count] == 0)
    {

        [newListManager.requestNotFilledList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Request *request, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {


            [self.requestManager.requestNotFilledList insertObject:request atIndex:index];
            [insertIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];

        }];
    } else { 


        __block BOOL foundMatch;
        [self.requestManager.requestNotFilledList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Request *oldReq, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

            foundMatch = false;

            [newListManager.requestNotFilledList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Request *newReq, NSUInteger newIdx, BOOL *stop) {

                if ([oldReq.requestID isEqualToString:newReq.requestID])
                {
                    foundMatch = true;
                    *stop = YES;
                }

            }];

            if (foundMatch == false)
            {
                [deleteIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
                [self.requestManager.requestNotFilledList removeObjectAtIndex:index];
            }

        }];

        [newListManager.requestNotFilledList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Request *newReq, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

            foundMatch = false;

            [self.requestManager.requestNotFilledList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Request *oldReq, NSUInteger oldIdx, BOOL *stop) {

                if ([oldReq.requestID isEqualToString:newReq.requestID])
                {
                    foundMatch = true;
                    *stop = YES;
                }

            }];

            if (foundMatch == false)
            {
                [insertIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
                [self.requestManager.requestNotFilledList insertObject:newReq atIndex:index];
            }

        }];

    }

    NSLog(@"After - requestNotFilledList count = %lu", (unsigned long)self.requestManager.requestNotFilledList.count);

    UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.view;

    [tv beginUpdates];
    [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tv endUpdates];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about inserting the new indexPaths and deleting the unneeded indexPaths with animation:

```
- insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
- deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

You need to have an array of indexPaths to remove, let's say you have an array [1,2,3,6] and you remove 2 and 6, you need to have the array indexPaths for rows 1 and 3.

Also, you need to have an array of the indexPaths you want to insert: let's say you add a,b,c like this: [a,**1**,**3**,b,**c**,7], so the indexPaths will be for rows - 0,3,4.

I've made a simple code just for an example: the starting data in my tableView is [1,2,3,4,5,6], and in the following code I update it to [1, **new1**, 2, **new2**, 3, 5, **new3**, 7]. The tricky part is to calculate the indextPaths for insertion and deletion.

```
- (void)updateTableView
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    // First remove the objects
    [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:5];
    [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:3];

    NSArray *indexPathsToRemove = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0],
                                   [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0], nil];

    // Insert the new ones
    [self.dataArray insertObject:@"New data 3" atIndex:4];
    [self.dataArray insertObject:@"New data 2" atIndex:2];
    [self.dataArray insertObject:@"New data 1" atIndex:1];

    NSArray *indexPathsToInsert = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0],
                               [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0],
                               [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:6 inSection:0], nil];

    // Animate the insertion and deletion
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

}

You Always need to consider the deletion before the insertion, in an animationBlock by 'beginUpdats', the tableView ins't insert new rows or sections until it has handled all the deletions.

Comment: I am using a singleton array to hold my objects... Therefore, I would need to copy that array when I get new data from the server, and compare it to the existing array that is the tableView dataSource. How do I know what indexPaths to delete, and what ones to Insert?

Comment: I guess you can run over the original array, and when an object is not in the new array, you add its index to the indexPaths for deletion. And then run over the new array, when an object is not in the original array, add its index to the indexPaths for insertion.